# Corroborating 2 large Python dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Say I have a 2 dictionaries, each with around 100000 entries (each can be of different length):

```py
dict1 = {"a": ["w", "x"], "b":["y"], "c":["z"] ...}
dict2 = {"x": ["a", "b"], "y":["b", "d"], "z":["d"] ...}
```

I need to perform an operation using these two dictionaries:

- Treat each dict item as a set of mapping (i.e list of all mappings in `dict1` would be`"a"->"w"`, `"a"->"x"`, `"b"->"y"` and `"c"->"z"`)
- Only keep mappings in `dict1` if the reverse mapping exists in `dict2`.

The resulting dictionary would be:
`{"a": ["x"], "b", ["y"]}`

My current solution uses 2 `m*n` all zeros dataframes where `m` and `n` are the lengths of `dict1` and `dict2` respectively and the index labels are the keys in `dict1` and the column labels are the keys in `dict2`.

For the first dataframe, I insert a `1` at each value where the index label -> column label represent a mapping in `dict1`. For the second dataframe, I insert a `1` at each value where the column label -> index label represent a mapping in `dict2`.

I then perform an element-size product between the two dataframes, which only leaves values that have a mapping `"a1"->"x1"` in `dict1` and `"x1"->"a1"` in `dict2`.

However, this takes up way too much memory and is very expensive. Is there an alternative algorithm I can use?

Comment: How long are the lists?

Comment: Also, does the order of the value lists matter at all? Do they even have to be lists?

Comment: The dict values are lists of length around 2-5 but there may be outliers

Comment: I didn't realize you were looking for a single output rather than an update to both inputs. Updated my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to use the same idea, but replace a sparse matrix you're using with a set of key pairs? Something like:

```
import collections
def fn(dict1, dict2):
    mapping_set = set()
    for k, vv in dict2.items():
        for v in vv:
            mapping_set.add((k, v))
    result_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k, vv in dict1.items():
        for v in vv:
            if (v, k) in mapping_set:  # Note reverse order of k and v
                result_dict[k].append(v)
    return result_dict
```

**Update**: It will use `O(total number of values in dict2)` of memory and `O(total number of values in dict1) + O(total number of values in dict2)` time - both a linear. It's not possible to solve the problem algorithmically faster as every value in every dict has to be visited at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have python objects to begin with, you may want to stay in the python domain. If you need to iterate through the entire dict to create your matrix anyway, you may find that filtering in-place doesn't take much longer.

```
default = ()
result = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2.get(v, default)}
```

If your list are short, this will be totally fine. If they contain many elements, linear search will start to compare to the overhead of set lookup. In that case, you may want to preprocess `dict2` to contain `set`s rather than lists:

```
dict2 = {k: set(v) for k, v in dict2.items}
```

or in-place

```
for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict2[k] = set(v)
```